# Why rainbow colors are as they are?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

There are handful of questions related to rainbow formation here already, but after looking into them, I feel that I must ask yet another one.

I did a little research on the subject, and most of the articles or youtube videos tend to focus on refraction-reflection-refraction in the single droplet part. The big picture, for some reason is expected to be self-evident after all that geometry and calculus put into finding maximum reflection angles for different wavelengths. Others will show a picture with two droplets and two rays of red and blue colors, where one ray of each color is missing observer's eye and have that as sufficient evidence. However, it's certainly not obvious moment for me.

So if I get it right, abstracting away all the calculus-geometry stuff, if we take beam of parallel single wavelength rays hitting a perfect spherical droplet, it is going to be reflected in the shape of cone with the apex at the droplet, where half-angle depends on the wavelength (I like the image used for illustration in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/464058/))

Taking into account that white solar light is actually composition of spectrum, we can replace every droplet of water by a tiny light which will emit white light inside the cone with 40° half-angle, then on the edge of that cone we'll start losing violet, then blue, then green and so on up to 42° where we'll have only red left.

Now from the observer's point of view, those droplets that are closer than 40° from antisolar point are going to reflect white light, and that matches with my observation: area inside rainbow is slightly brighter than outside.

Yet as we get closer to 40°, the magic called "the rainbow" starts, and that's where my understanding gets in conflict with reality:

Droplets at 40° reflect towards the observer all the light except violet. Respectively, I would expect to see inner rainbow ring as white except violet, i.e. bright green. Then with reduction of blue and then green it should have gotten more and more yellow. To my best understanding we should see kind of "cumulative spectrum" (in lack of better words I just coined this term), with no light outside the 42°(check), starting with red (check again), through the yellow to green at 40°, but without blue and violet (wrong), with just white inside the 40° ring (check again):

```
Red => Red
Orange => Red+Orange = Red
Yellow => Red+Orange+Yellow = Orange
Green => Red+Orange+Yellow+Green = Yellow
Blue => Red+Orange+Yellow+Green+Blue = Green
Violet => Red+Orange+Yellow+Green+Blue+Violet = White
```

[image]

As apparently we are able to see blue and weak, but clear violet stripe in the rainbow, my understanding is wrong. So why don't we get red, yellow, green and blue light in it as well? Why do we see spectrum as if we were using prism, not the "cumulative spectrum"?

Comment: After finishing writing this question, I figured that it might be caused by the fact that intensity of outgoing rays is not evenly distributed across the cone, so besides cutting off, droplet also effectively focuses considerable fraction of every wavelength in some region close to its maximum angle, producing fuzzy, but still readable spectrum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a rainbow show all of its colours?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/709484/how-does-a-rainbow-show-all-of-its-colours)

Comment: @Farcher not exactly. I saw that answer and it has very same issue as all the rest I mentioned: it assumes there is only one ray hitting every droplet at exactly same spot relative to the center line. However, in reality beam hits every point on the droplet surface and there are going to be multiple outgoing rays of different wavelengths going out at any given angle up to maximum: so even looking at single droplet, along with the violet ray we will also get blue, green, yellow and so on, just from slightly different entry points on the droplet: their maximum angles are bigger, aren't they?

Comment: I've added an image. Have to steal crayons from my son, so please don't be too harsh :-)

Comment: Although it doesn't address the issue of overlapping colours, Dale's diagram may be helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/774781/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you, I saw that one too. It is pretty helpful in terms of original question, but you are right: it doesn't address the issue with overlapping colors.

Thinking about this during the last couple days, I already have pretty clearly picture of vision and light cones that produce the rainbow, and in fact we probably can see it on the surface of single raindrop, or even clear glass marble lit with beam of sunlight. I'll see if I can steal one from my son too :) I bet there is going to be normal rainbow, not "cumulative" one.

Comment: It's fun to make a "water prism", using a flat tray full of water, and a small mirror set at an angle in the water. Using this setup, you can get a spectacular looking spectrum from sunlight on a white wall. Of course, such a spectrum is a bit different to a rainbow, since a spectrum from a single refractor doesn't have anywhere near the same amount of blurring as you get in a rainbow.

Comment: See also [What do individual rainbow-forming drops look like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/408618/what-do-individual-rainbow-forming-droplets-look-like)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you, I missed those questions, and the second one has great renders that effectively contain answer to my question. Yet this question is entirely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the addition of some good diagrams I think I now understand your question.

This diagram does not show a key feature of the reflections.

[image]

The intensity of the reflected rays varies and so you do not observe a uniform cone of reflected light.

Here is a gif animation to show you what I mean.

[image]

[Individual images were taken from an [Atmospheric Optics webpage](https://atoptics.co.uk/rainbows/primrays.htm) and combined to produce a gif file.]

Parallel rays are coming in at the top of a water droplet and refracted, reflected and refracted again to emerge from the bottom half of the drop.

What you should note is that for a given range of impact parameters of the incident rays the highest concentration of emergent rays occurs occurs around an angle of $137.5^\circ$, ie that is where the emergent light is brightest and light from around that angle swamps the light from that emerging at other angles.
So you diagram should show a high intensity of red light around a particular direction and and much lower elsewhere.

[image]

Here is a ray diagram to illustrate the "bunching" of light rays along a particular direction.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. I had suspicion about it myself but didn't get to actual calculation of outgoing intensity distribution. It seems bearable, so I'll try it anyway.